# WPF Picture Viewer (why is image dancing around)

Tags: c#, wpf, image, stretch

I'm trying to create a simple Window that allows viewing/zooming/moving an image. It is starting to behave similar to what it should with the image resizing to adjust to the window as we resize.

The weird thing is that as you reduce the width of the window, at a certain point, the height of the picture starts reducing when it shouldn't, and then it bounces into a different position. In the code, however, the height of the image remains the same so "something" else is altering the layout.

The other weird thing is that as you increase the width, the image almost remains centered except that it gradually tilts towards the right.

So my question is: what is screwing up my layout like this?

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            x:Class="NaturalGroundingPlayer.ImageViewerWindow"
            x:Name="Window" Title="Image Viewer" Width="640" Height="480" SizeChanged="Window_SizeChanged">
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Canvas x:Name="ImgCanvas" ClipToBounds="True">
            <ContentControl x:Name="ImgContentCtrl" Height="300" Width="400">
                <Grid x:Name="ImgGrid">
                    <Image x:Name="ImgObject"/>
                    <Thumb x:Name="ImgThumb" Opacity="0" DragDelta="ImgThumb_DragDelta" MouseWheel="ImgThumb_MouseWheel"/>
                </Grid>
            </ContentControl>
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
</Window>



public partial class ImageViewerWindow : Window {
    public static ImageViewerWindow Instance(string fileName) {
        ImageViewerWindow NewForm = new ImageViewerWindow();
        NewForm.LoadImage(fileName);
        NewForm.Show();
        return NewForm;
    }

    private double scale;

    public ImageViewerWindow() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void LoadImage(string fileName) {
        BitmapImage NewImage = new BitmapImage();
        NewImage.BeginInit();
        NewImage.UriSource = new Uri(fileName);
        NewImage.EndInit();
        ImgObject.Source = NewImage;
        //ImgContentCtrl.Width = NewImage.Width;
        //ImgContentCtrl.Height = NewImage.Height;
        BestFit();
    }

    private void ImgThumb_DragDelta(object sender, DragDeltaEventArgs e) {
        double ImgLeft = Canvas.GetLeft(ImgContentCtrl);
        double ImgTop = Canvas.GetTop(ImgContentCtrl);
        Canvas.SetLeft(ImgContentCtrl, (ImgLeft + e.HorizontalChange));
        Canvas.SetTop(ImgContentCtrl, (ImgTop + e.VerticalChange));
    }

    private void ImgThumb_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e) {
        // Zoom in when the user scrolls the mouse wheel up and vice versa.
        if (e.Delta > 0) {
            // Limit zoom-in to 500%
            if (scale < 5) 
                scale += 0.1;
        } else {
            // When mouse wheel is scrolled down...
            // Limit zoom-out to 80%
            if (scale > 0.8) 
                scale -= 0.1;
        }
        DisplayImage();
    }

    private void BestFit() {
        // Set the scale of the ContentControl to 100%.
        scale = 1;

        // Set the position of the ContentControl so that the image is centered.
        Canvas.SetLeft(ImgContentCtrl, 0);
        Canvas.SetTop(ImgContentCtrl, 0);
    }

    private void Window_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e) {
        DisplayImage();
    }

    private void DisplayImage() {
        double RatioWidth = LayoutRoot.ActualWidth / ImgObject.Source.Width;
        double RatioHeight = LayoutRoot.ActualHeight / ImgObject.Source.Height;
        if (RatioHeight > RatioWidth) {
            ImgContentCtrl.Width = LayoutRoot.ActualWidth * scale;
            ImgContentCtrl.Height = LayoutRoot.ActualHeight * RatioHeight * scale;
        } else {
            ImgContentCtrl.Height = LayoutRoot.ActualHeight * scale;
            ImgContentCtrl.Width = LayoutRoot.ActualWidth * RatioWidth * scale;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried to run it. Application fails with NullReferenceException on the first line of `DisplayImage()`. `ImgObject.Source` is not assigned. Have I missed something or do you need to add something?

Comment: @EtienneCharland I don't see what you're trying to achieve here but did you try simply `ImgContentCtrl.Width = LayoutRoot.ActualWidth * scale;` and `ImgContentCtrl.Height = LayoutRoot.ActualHeight * scale;`, without need for `RatioWidth` and `RatioHeight`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sjips, you first need to put any picture in it to display.

dkozl, that works indeed, I wasn't sure the Image control would respect proportions automatically as the demo I found wasn't respecting proportions while resizing. Simply putting this code in DisplayImage works perfect, even for repositioning properly when zooming. I guess I was much closer to the answer than I thought!

```
private void DisplayImage() {
    ImgContentCtrl.Width = LayoutRoot.ActualWidth * scale;
    Canvas.SetLeft(ImgContentCtrl, LayoutRoot.ActualWidth * (1 - scale) / 2);
    ImgContentCtrl.Height = LayoutRoot.ActualHeight * scale;
    Canvas.SetTop(ImgContentCtrl, LayoutRoot.ActualHeight * (1 - scale) / 2);
}
```

That being said, I still don't undestand the weird behaviors that happened before...